# UnitsNet: Render a value as a string with the full name of the unit?

Tags: c#, units-of-measurement

Using [UnitsNet](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet), if I have, for example, a `len` value ...

```cs
var len = Length.FromMiles(60);
```

... rendering it as a string always yields the unit of measure in its abbreviated form:

```cs
len.ToString(); // "60 mi"
```

Is there a `ToString` overload that yields the full name of the unit of measure? E.g.,

```cs
len.ToString(???); // "60 miles"
```

(*FYI, I am using [version 4.36.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnitsNet/4.36.0) of the package.*)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [String Formatting](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet/wiki/String-Formatting) documentation for that library, there are specified format strings for the `Value` (`"v"`) and the `Unit` ('`"u"`) that can be used to show a combination of the value and the full unit name.

According to the samples, you can do the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("Length is {0:v} {0:u}s", len);

// Output: "Length is 60 Miles"
```

Other ways to do it:

```
len.ToString("v") + " " + len.ToString("u") + "s"
// or
$"{len:v} {len:u}s"
// will produce: "60 Miles"
```

---

Noticing that we have to call `ToString` twice, separate the calls with a space, and the unit is capitalized and not "pluralized", it may be worthwhile to write an extension method to help with the formatting. It will also allow us to handle special cases like units that are compound words (which should have spaces or hyphens in the name) and units whose plural form is something other than just adding an `'s'` at the end:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<LengthUnit, string> CompoundWordUnits =
        new Dictionary<LengthUnit, string>
        {
            {LengthUnit.AstronomicalUnit, "astronomical unit"},
            {LengthUnit.DtpPica, "dtp pica"},
            {LengthUnit.DtpPoint, "dtp point"},
            {LengthUnit.KilolightYear, "kilolight-year"},
            {LengthUnit.LightYear, "light-year"},
            {LengthUnit.MegalightYear, "megalight-year"},
            {LengthUnit.NauticalMile, "nautical mile"},
            {LengthUnit.PrinterPica, "printer pica"},
            {LengthUnit.PrinterPoint, "printer point"},
            {LengthUnit.SolarRadius, "solar radius"},
            {LengthUnit.UsSurveyFoot, "US survey foot"},
        };

    private static readonly Dictionary<LengthUnit, string> SpecialPluralUnits =
        new Dictionary<LengthUnit, string>
        {
            {LengthUnit.Foot, "feet"},
            {LengthUnit.Inch, "inches"},
            {LengthUnit.Microinch, "microinches"},
            {LengthUnit.SolarRadius, "solar radii"},
            {LengthUnit.UsSurveyFoot, "US survey feet"},
        };

    public static string ToGramaticallyCorrectString(this Length length)
    {
        if (length == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(length));

        // Get the singular form
        var unit = CompoundWordUnits.ContainsKey(length.Unit)
            ? CompoundWordUnits[length.Unit]
            : length.Unit.ToString().ToLower();

        // Get the plural form if needed
        if (length.Value != 1)
            unit = SpecialPluralUnits.ContainsKey(length.Unit)
                ? SpecialPluralUnits[length.Unit]
                : $"{unit}s";

        return $"{length:v} {unit}";
    }
}
```

With this in place we can now do:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lengths = new List<Length>
    {
        Length.FromMiles(1),
        Length.FromMiles(1).ToUnit(LengthUnit.Foot),
        Length.FromMiles(1).ToUnit(LengthUnit.LightYear),
        Length.FromMiles(1).ToUnit(LengthUnit.UsSurveyFoot),
        Length.FromUsSurveyFeet(1),
    };

    lengths.ForEach(length => Console.WriteLine(length.ToGramaticallyCorrectString()));

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You can also do `len.ToString("u")` and `len.ToString("v")` although it doesn't pluralize units by itself, it seems.